# Unreachable "i" in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do a multiplication table and I get an "Unreachable code detected" error in my code on my "i". Is it because I don't have an IF? or how can I solve this?

```
public int[,] CalculateMultMatrix()
{
     int[,] multTable = new int[10, 10];
     for(int i = 1; 1 <= 10; i++)
     {
         for(int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
         {
             multTable[i - 1, j - 1] = i * j;                    
         }
         return multTable;
     }
 }
```

Comment: You have a typo `1 <= 10` rather than `i <= 10`. Also your end conditions want to be strictly less than 10 as c# arrays start at index 0. Plus you are returning from *within* the outer loop. Is this what you want?

Comment: the return is also iffy (answer now deleted) `i` will only ever equal 1.

Answer (score 5):

The first problem is that you are comparing `1 <= 10`. `1` will always be smaller than `10`. Change it to `for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)`.

Second problem: You are returning `multTable` inside the loop. The method will be finished before `i++` gets called.

Comment: This does not cause the compiler error.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice the second sentence does?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice "*Unreachable code detected*" is a warning, not a compiler error.

Comment: Either way, this is not the cause. It only creates an infinite loop, not unreachable code.

Comment: This is not an infinite loop as OP uses `return` inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks for all the good answers! Thou its not printing anything now. What should the statement be in the Main file? Or is it anything else im missing? I´m totally new to Coding so sorry for maybe obvious questions :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the `return` statement. It is inside the outer `i` loop. 
Just put it outside the loop. Also, correct the typo mentioned in the comments of the questions.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
 {
     for(int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
     {
         multTable[i - 1, j - 1] = i * j;                    
     }
 }
 return multTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning `multTable` within the loop, so `i` will only ever be 1. This is the cause of the warning, as `i++` can never be called it is 'unreachable'.

You likely meant to return it after the two loops had completed.  You also have what looks like a typo - the condition `1 <= 10` will always be `true`. You need to fix this as well, else the loop will never complete.

```
int[,] multTable = new int[10, 10];

for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    for(int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
    {
        multTable[i - 1, j - 1] = i * j;                    
    }
}

return multTable;
```

Comment: Thanks for all the good answers! Thou its not printing anything now. What should the statement be in the Main file?

Comment: @hippimaster you should post a new question

Answer (score 0):

In line 4, the phrase `1 <= 10` will always be `true`.

Comment: This does not cause the compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

```
return multTable;
```

This causes all execution to stop in the current function. You get the error because `i++` will never have a chance to execute in your for loop.

p.s. While the other answers point out another problem in your code, they do not address the cause of the compiler error.